# Unresolved identifier 'CALayerContentsGravity' in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

The below code works well with "Swift 3" but giving error of "unresolved identifier `CALayerContentsGravity`" in "Swift 4"

```
static func create(image: UIImage, size: Double) -> CALayer {
    let containerLayer = createContainerLayer(size)
    let imageLayer = createContainerLayer(size)
    containerLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
    imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage
    imageLayer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspect
    return containerLayer
}
```

Comment: self.view.layer.contentsGravity = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspect.......works for me in swift 4.

Comment: The code looks proper, can you pls provide us screenshot of error?

Answer (score 2):

In **swift4** `CALayerContentsGravity` is not working.

To set `contentsGravity` of layer you should use constant string which is available in swift4.

```
imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem after I imported the Cosmos pod. I spoke to the author and he said I need to check the pod's target and the Swift language it used.

When I check the Cosmos target the Swift version was 4 but my main project used Swift 4.2. Once I changed the Cosmos pod's version from 4 to 4.2 the error went away.

[suggestion from Cosmos author](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos/issues/130#issuecomment-479674652)

This is how you check the Cosmos pod Swift version
[image]

It needs to match what's in your main project's target:

[image]